# Get list of all installed X applications

Tags: linux, command-line, arch-linux, xorg

In all the different Linux desktop environments there is usually a list of all the (xorg) programs that can be run.

For example in my most recent Linux install (Arch running the Deepin Desktop Environment) if you press the Windows/Mac key it brings up a list of all the applications that use xorg, and shows what ones where installed recently.

How do I get that list of the installed xorg applications/packages from the command line?

Comment: I never used Deepin Desktop Environment, but those DE tend to look the list in `/usr/share/applications`, so I don't think that Deepen Desktop Environment is showing the list of all the applications that use xorg (e.g. `xmessage`).

Comment: @ymonad Oh sweet! Exactly what I was looking for, If you make an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desktop entries for applications, or .desktop files, are generally a combination of meta information resources and a shortcut of an application. These files usually reside in `/usr/share/applications` or `/usr/local/share/applications` for applications installed system-wide, or `~/.local/share/applications` for user-specific applications. User entries take precedence over system entries.

source :https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_entries

Comment: Maybe you also should point out that this is *not* a list of *all* "xorg" programs, there are many more, which just don't happen to have a desktop entry.